# /summon Item bug?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, I've been having various issues with summoning Item entities. Often it actually summons the entity, but it doesn't allow me to pick it up. I've tried almost everything I can think of, yet it's still fruitless. I've even tried setting `PickupDelay` to 0!

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you paste the command you're attempting to use?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this command with setting the PickupDelay to 1

```
/summon Item ~ ~1 ~ {Item:{id:iron_axe,Count:1},PickupDelay:1}
```

Using a `PickUpDelay` of 1 means setting the tick to 1

You can also try this same command that makes the item never despawn

```
/summon Item ~ ~1 ~ {Item:{id:iron_axe,Count:1},PickupDelay:1,Age:-32768}
```

This is the same command but making the item never despawn as the age is set to -32768

Comment: `PickupDelay` isn't the issue. However, the command you've presented will fix his issue because you've set `Count` to 1. It defaults to 0 when unspecified, which prevents the item from being picked up.